# How to load only one class from module?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-import

I have code:

```
mod_file = 'mymod.py'
mod_path = os.path.join('.', mod_file)
mod_py = 'mymod'
mod = imp.load_source(mod_py, mod_path)
if hasattr(mod, 'MyClass'):
    instance = py_mod.MyClass()
```

mymod.py:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello'
    [...]

print 'something'
a = MyClass()
```

But "imp.load_source" execute all instructions from this file. I want only get class MyClass - and other thigns skip. How to do it?

Edit:

I can not interfere in the "mymod.py" file, and I do not know how the file will be named, this is example.

I know that in the file will be class 'MyClass'. Other things are undesirable.

Comment: I'm not sure you can accomplish what you are looking for (without jumping through tons of hoops and introspecting module's source code). If you want to isolate module initialization, I recommend separating the code into multiple modules, and only import those you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the end lines in `mymod.py` like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'something'
    a = MyClass()
```

The result will be these lines are only executed when `mymod.py` is executed as a script, not imported as a module.See [executing modules as scripts](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts) in the Python documentation.

Note however, that if you have other classes defined in `mymod.py` they will still be imported by `imp.load_source`.

**Edit**: as you are unable to modify `mymod.py` the solution becomes more complicated.  You can use the [ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module to parse the code:

```
import ast
with open("mymod.py", "r") as fd:
    module_ast = ast.parse("".join(fd.readlines()))
```

You would then traverse the ast (`module_ast`) and isolate the `MyClass` tree node.  This link gives an [example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/28/python-internals-working-with-python-asts/) of modifying python code inline, and this shows how to [analyse code](http://www.andreas-dewes.de/en/2012/static-code-analysis-with-python/).  You could use a combination of techniques from those links to isolate `ast` nodes related to `MyClass` and delete the rest.  But this would end up making a number of assumptions about what `mymod.py` actually contains.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in Python. You should design your code so that it has no side-effects when it's imported.

Also, note that modules are only executed **once**, regardless of how many times you use `import module` on them, so it's a **very bad idea** to rely on side effects at module import.

Nonetheless, if what you need is to have your module behave differently when it's imported than when it's run, then you can achieve that goal by using:

```
# module.py
# Code that will always run
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Code that will only run if you do python module.py
    # Usually print statements, argument parsing... 
    ...
```

---

In your case, you would do:

```
    class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello'
    [...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'something'
    a = MyClass()
```

---

An usual way of using this is by doing:

```
def main():
     # do stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello'
    [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'something'
    a = MyClass()
```

All statements in the `if __name__` block get executed only if that module is executed directly and not when the module is imported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most pythonic solution here would be to just import the class from your other Python file. To do this, replace your imp.load_source() with:

```
 from mymod import MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step #1** - create file `main.py` with the following code:

```
from MyFolder import MyClass
instance = MyClass()
# Do whatever you wanna do with the MyClass instance...
```

**Step #2** - create folder `MyFolder` next to file `main.py`.

**Step #3** - rename file `mymod.py` to `__init__.py`, and put it inside folder `MyFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't write your own plug-in system.  There are too many of them already.
2. While it is theoretically possible to inspect the AST of a module to only extract only the bits you need, this will in practice lead to all kind of weird corner cases, and it is a Bad Idea.  Don't do it.  Require plug-ins to be written in a way that they can be imported without side effects.